# Can I upgrade my php version 5.3.13 vc9 x64 to a vc11 or vc14 variant?

Tags: php, wampserver, php-5.3

I will really appreciate your guidance on this please guys.
I run php version 5.3.13 and apache version 2.2.12 vc9 x64 on my wamp local server and wish to upgrade to a more recent version. However, I observed on the php.net page that php 5.6 has only the vc11 variant while php 7 has vc 14 variant. What options do I have to upgrade to from my current version? Can someone assist with a step to step guide of how to get this done with minimal risk to my files please.

Comment: Please explain why exactly you mean by "vc11 variant" and "vc14 variant".

Comment: You will have to upgrade your Apache to `2.4.something` where the apache version is also compiled with vc11 or vc14

Comment: You might find life easier if you used WAMPServer

Comment: On php.net the available upgrade versions are 5.6 vc11 x64 & x86 versions and php 7 vc14 x64 and x86 versions. My current version of vc9 isn't available

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using wamp server

Comment: What version of WAMPServer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Wampserver 2.2.22

Comment: Then take a backup of all your databases and your site code. Uninstall your current version and install WAMPServer 3.0.6. Then apply the 3.0.8 upgrade. [All can be found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Then you can install any of the ADDONS for various versions of PHP/Apache/MYSQL or even MariaDB. The addons can also be found on that page

Comment: Please take note of the Install Dialog that describes the MSVC Runtimes required. Be sure to install all those first. **Big Note** these will not work on Windows XP if you are still running that version of Windows

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks so much for your assistance. To be very sure,I guess by addons u mean corresponding versions of phpmyadmin, php,mysql and apache?How about the visual c++ packages, will there be need to download this too?

Comment: To run all possible versions of Apache/PHP you will need all the MSVC runtimes. If you look at the bottom of the page I linked you to, there is a ALL MSVC runtime installer that you might find userful

Comment: Thanks so much @RiggsFolly. Will try to do the upgrade and feed you back.

Comment: Make sure you do the backups first. Just in case you get a hiccup on the way

Comment: Thanks sir..will do just that

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks a million. Everything is fine now